# ¿Cuál es el origen exacto de la expresión "hacer la peseta"?

Tags: etimología, expresiones, españa, vulgaridades

Intentando buscar el origen de la palabra "peseta" en su sentido despectivo y obsceno, me he topado con una pequeña confusión. Os cuento lo que llevo:

Empecemos por la definición de la RAE:

> **[hacer la peseta](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Sn1lzAO#32yov2L)**
>
> 1. loc. verb. vulg. Dar un corte de mangas.

De aquí llegamos a:

> [**corte de manga**, o **corte de mangas**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=B21cQlz#1DixjQT)
>
> 1. m. vulgs. Ademán de significado obsceno y despectivo que se hace con la mano, a veces extendiendo el dedo corazón entre el índice y el anular doblados. A la vez se levanta el brazo doblado y se golpea en él con la otra mano. *Dar, hacer un corte de mangas.*

Este es el sentido que yo entiendo como "hacer la peseta", que es extendiendo el dedo corazón por encima del resto de dedos plegados. Buscando por qué se le dio a este gesto el nombre de "peseta", encuentro que José María Iribarren, en su libro *El porqué de los dichos*, explica que proviene del reverso de peseta columnaria, equivalente a cinco reales, donde aparece la columna de Gades. Según su análisis, de la semejanza entre esta figura y el dedo en posición vertical nació la expresión que ha llegado hasta nuestros días.

Igualmente, Francisco Rodríguez Marín escribe:

> Véase la peseta columnaria de las que valen cinco reales; repárese la disposición en que están figurados en el reverso los dos mundos y la columna de Gades y se notará que medianamente lo semeja la mano en la actitud sobredicha.

Y aquí es donde me hallo atascado. La imagen de la peseta columnaria que encuentro es la siguiente:

[image: Peseta columnaria]

La imagen representa los dos mundos bajo una misma corona, efectivamente, pero no tiene una columna sino dos. Mis dudas son, pues:

- ¿Me estoy equivocando de moneda? Una búsqueda en Google Imágenes de "peseta columnaria" o "peseta columnaria cinco reales" da esta imagen como resultado entre otras, pero esta es la que más se parece a la descripción.
- ¿La expresión "hacer la peseta" podría referirse originalmente al gesto de hacer los cuernos? La imagen parece representar este gesto mucho mejor, con las columnas representando los dedos índice y meñique. Sin embargo, las expresiones "hacer la peseta" o "corte de mangas" son de inserción reciente en el DRAE (finales del siglo XX), así que no tengo significados previos como referencia.

El caso es que no puedo encontrar ninguna referencia a la expresión ni en el [CORDE](http://corpus.rae.es/cordenet.html) ni en la [hemeroteca de la Biblioteca Nacional](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/index.vm). Así que se me ocurre que pueda ser una expresión en realidad bastante reciente como para asociarla a una moneda del siglo XVIII. ¿Existe alguna otra teoría sobre el origen de esta expresión?

Comment: `extendiendo el dedo corazón por encima del resto de dedos plegados` Qué tal si tal gesto obsceno fuese extendiendo índice y meñique mientras se mantienen el resto plegados? En mis tiempos este era un "corte de mangas" más popular que el del dedo medio (se le decía _hacer_ los cuernos) y tiene más similitud con esas dos columnas a los lados que la "peineta" del dedo corazón. Básicamente en el corte de mangas que hacías con los brazos, podías mostrar un puño, los cuernos (índice y meñique), o el dedo medio. Así quie creo que te contesrtas tú mismo en el penúltimo párrafo...

Comment: Apparently (I believe everything [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bras_d%27honneur) says) in English we call this the Iberian slap or use the French phrase Bras d'honneur. I must say that I have never heard it called anything although the gesture does exist. The French entry in Wikepedia is quite amusing too if you read French. When I have seen it used as a gesture of triumph by footballers they use a clenched fist (_mostrar un puño_)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo habría dicho que las columnas se asemejan más al gesto de "los cuernos" (índice y meñique) que al del "dedo medio extendido" (solo sea porque hay **dos** columnas...). Sin embargo, parece que el gesto con el dedo medio sí fue bautizado a raíz de la moneda columnaria. Parece estar investigado y documentado por José María Iribarren, en su libro ‘El porqué de los dichos’. Lo que sigue es lo que he podido aprender leyendo [este artículo](http://www.diariosur.es/sociedad/201506/19/peseta-cuernos-gestos-historia-20150619202219.html).

---

La extensión del dedo corazón de la mano con el puño cerrado se bautizó como 'peseta' por el reverso de una moneda, aunque también se le conoce como 'peineta'.

El gesto ya se usaba en la antigua Grecia. El primer registro de este gesto aparece en la comedia 'Las nubes', escrita por Aristófanes en el año 423 a. c. Más tarde, los romanos lo bautizaron como el 'dígitus impudicos' (dedo impúdico), utilizándolo también como gesto de mofa o insulto. Básicamente el dedo extendido representa el pene y el resto de dedos cerrados los testículos, y el gesto califica como sodomita pasivo a aquel a quien se dirige (así que la peineta es una "versión muda" del "vete a tomar por el c...").

En la Roma clásica también se hacían los cuernos (extender, horizontal o verticalmente, los dedos índice y meñique manteniendo doblados los demás dedos) , pero no tenía el significado de burla que posee en la actualidad, sino uno mágico de "alejar el mal de ojo". Es parecido al gesto de "tocar madera", tocando un mueble o la cabeza, para "descargar" el mal *yuyu* como si los cuernos fueran una "toma de tierra mágica".

Pero para ir al grano, José María Iribarren, en su libro ‘El porqué de los dichos’, explica que el término "hacer la peseta" proviene del reverso de peseta columnaria, equivalente a cinco reales, donde aparece la columna de Gades.

> Según su análisis, de la semejanza entre esta figura y el dedo en posición vertical nació la expresión que ha llegado hasta nuestros días.

Real Academia de la Lengua recoge "peineta" con este significado, mientras que sí se refiere a ‘hacer la peseta’ como “dar un corte de mangas”.

---

Así que parece ser que aunque la moneda tenga dos columnas y "la peineta" sea un gesto de un dedo (mientras que los cuernos son dos dedos), entre unas cosas y otras la asociación se hizo de la imagen de la moneda al "dígitus impúdicos".

Comment: Peineta no aparece en el DLE con ese significado. En realidad es un error que cometió Luis Aragonés que dijo "peineta" en lugar de "peseta" y la prensa deportiva le dió pábulo; se ha extendido tanto su uso que mucha gente solo conoce el término peineta. Yo ni siquiera sabía que ese gesto tenía nombre hasta que empecé a oir "hacer la peineta".